# Is the Magento 2 community dead? (not getting answers)

Tags: discussion, magento2, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I'm just curious how active the Magento 2 community is . I've asked couple of questions and no one is answering. Also noticed a lot of questions unanswered. Is the M2 community dead or its just that there aren't too many Magento 2 devs?

Comment: Not sure about the community but for me... I'm not dead. I checked.

Comment: Haha! good to know.

Comment: magento 2 community is busy migrating all the sh-load of custom code from m1

Answer (score 4):

from what I see your questions tend to be quite broad feature requests. These seldom get proper answers here.
I can recommend narrowing them down and adding things like what you have tried so far. Any code that is failing, specific errors the community can help you with.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your feedback. I'll try to do just that.

Comment: I have asked many questions.none of any broad feature requests,although it is not answerd

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 community is not dead but there are few reason for not getting response very soon as you get on stackoverflow because:

1. There are less number of Magento developer as compared to core PHP
   web developers and more less developers of Magento 2 framework who
   are expert.
2. Writing code of Magento 2 questions requires more effort.
3. Even if developer knows that answer if it requires lot of verification and writing lot of coding he skips that question.

Comment: That makes sense. It might be one of the reasons I'm not getting any answers. Its just tough for new comers to Magento like me to figure things out on our own that is why we are seeking out for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No Magento 2 community is not dead it's working hard to resolve issue which are faced by us.I know there are very few discussion on magento community is just because of less magento 2 developer but still it help many new magento developers and it's a grate place to learn things.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 community is not dead, most of the question which are not answered are the ones that are not even following Question/Answer format of the site, if question is just mentioning a feature that is required/ I am getting this error and no logs , no debugging on your end etc. the person is just copy pasting client requirement / work assigned to him on stackexchange.

Such low quality and low effort posts are quite common on magento stackexchange where people have not yet mastered magento 2 fully.

In my honest opinion these posts should just be flagged "too broad" and closed.